# How would I dynamically clear form error while a user is typing

Tags: jquery

I have a contact form that uses AJAX.

Currently, when a user initially does not enter information into any of the required fields, an error message occurs. To clear that error message, a user must click the 'send' button.

What I am trying to do is this: If a user does not enter any info for any required field, but then starts typing and meets that field's requirement, the error message should clear automatically, rather than having to click the 'send' button again to make the error message disappear.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form #response').hide();


    $('.button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var valid = '';
        var required = ' is required.';
        var first = $('form #first').val();
        var last = $('form #last').val();
        var email = $('form #email').val();
        var message = $('form #message').val();
        var tempt = $('form #tempt').val();
        var tempt2 = $('form #tempt2').val();

        if (first = '' || first.length <= 1) {
            valid += '<p>Your first name' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (last = '' || last.length <= 1) {
            valid += '<p>Your last name' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
            valid += '<p>Your email address' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (message = '' || message.length <= 4) {
            valid += '<p>A message' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (tempt != 'http://') {
            valid += '<p>We can\'t allow spam bots.</p>';
        }

        if (tempt2 != '') {
            valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (valid != '') {
            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .html('' +valid).fadeIn('fast');
        }

        else {
            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Sending...').fadeIn('fast');

            var formData = $('form').serialize();
            submitForm(formData);
        }

    });

});

function submitForm(formData) {

    $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mail/mailform.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 4000,
            success: function(data) {

                            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                                            .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');

                            if ($('form #response').hasClass('success')) {
                                setTimeout("$('form #response').fadeOut('fast')", 4000);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                                    .html('<p>There was an <strong>' + errorThrown +
                                        '</strong> error due to an <strong>' + textStatus +
                                        '</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
                    },
                    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {

                        $('form')[0].reset();
                    }

          });


};


var required = ' is required.';
        var first = $('form #first').val();
        var first = $('form #first').keyup(function (event) {
        var first = $(this);
        if ($first.val() !== ''){
            $('form #response2').removeclass('response2');
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - First, remove validation from button, set it into a separated function because in this way you can use validation anywere , not just on your button click, like:

```
function IsValidForm() {

        e.preventDefault();

        var valid = '';
        var required = ' is required.';
        var first = $('form #first').val();
        var last = $('form #last').val();
        var email = $('form #email').val();
        var message = $('form #message').val();
        var tempt = $('form #tempt').val();
        var tempt2 = $('form #tempt2').val();

        if (first = '' || first.length <= 1) {
            valid += '<p>Your first name' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (last = '' || last.length <= 1) {
            valid += '<p>Your last name' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
            valid += '<p>Your email address' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (message = '' || message.length <= 4) {
            valid += '<p>A message' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (tempt != 'http://') {
            valid += '<p>We can\'t allow spam bots.</p>';
        }

        if (tempt2 != '') {
            valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (valid != '') {
            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .html('' +valid).fadeIn('fast');

            return false;
        }

        else {
          return true;
        }

}
```

Pay attention at the ending, if it throw some error to user `return false;` (is not valid), if it's all OK `return true;`

2 - Second, now you must set validation when user type at fields. **Make sure that code is under validation inputs, or is inside at onRead() function.**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( ".validationField" ).keydown(function() {
       //valid form when user enter data to "validationField" fields
       IsValidForm();
    });

});
```

add "validationField" class to fields that you want to validate when user types in, eg.:

```
<input type="text" id="email" class="validationField" />
```

There is! now this accomplish what you want, you just need to change at your sending button:

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(IsValidForm())
    {
         $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Sending...').fadeIn('fast');

        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        submitForm(formData);

    }

});
```

Now, you can realize that it'll valid the form at the very first user type, right? if you just want to start validating just after first form sending , you need to create a variable:

```
var hasSubmited = false;
```

and in your form send button, set:

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    hasSubmited = true;
    ...
```

and in your whole `IsValidForm()` validation function, encapsulate validation checking if this variable is true, your just a quick way:

```
function IsValid() {

        e.preventDefault();

        if(hasSubmited == false) return true;

        ...
```

now this will validate only after first form submit.